# how to hit an api on button click using laravel

Tags: laravel, api

i am new to working with API ,i have 2 buttons in my view file and i want to print the sheet which is available as an API ,

```
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            @include('admin.inc.messages')
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Back</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Print Airway Bill</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Print Invoice</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i have got the path , i want to ask where should i define the path for that , in the web.php or api.php
and second thing how should i give the path in the buttons

any help will be appreciated !

Comment: use ajax to get api response.

Comment: I suggest read/watch some tutorials on [creating APIs with Laravel](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+api+tutorial) as this will not be the only question you have. A lot of the already available tutorials cover the fundamentals and the most common questions you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consume your own api, most likely, or use ajax request. This can be done via passport, seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) in the documentation. If you want you can always bypass, however you will not have the ability to utilize middleware with those requests. Meaning, that your project will be subjected to potential security risk as the request will not be subjected to route middleware. Which protect and assist you in some regards.

For example, if you cannot authenticate against a middleware you will not have the ability to determine which/what user is requesting data. Another comparison one might make would be the ability to login against a user, but then not have the ability through out the application pages to know which user was authenticated. This is comparable to when you log in to stackoverflow you can obviously see you user information/profile in the top right with your picture etc... If you by pass you will not have that ability.

Therefore, I would highly recommend visiting the link posted above and consider consuming your own api or creating a service to do so.